# How to mock spring security authentication.getAuthorities()?

Tags: unit-testing, spring-security, mockito, junit5

I am trying to mock the `authentication.getAuthorities()` using junit5. I'm not able to mock it. Please suggest.

I have the following private method:

```java
private String populateAuthorities(Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> collection) {
    Set<String> authoritiesSet = new HashSet<>();
    for (GrantedAuthority authority : collection) { 
        authoritiesSet.add(authority.getAuthority());
    }
    return String.join(AppConstant.COMMA, authoritiesSet);
}
```

My full implementation is:

```java
@Component("jwtTokenGeneratorFilter")
@Log4j2
public class JwtTokenGeneratorFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(authentication) && authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserVO) {
            UserVO userVO = (UserVO) authentication.getPrincipal();
            if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(errorMessageKey)) {
                String jwt = Jwts.builder().setIssuer(AppConstant.IMS).setSubject(AppConstant.JWT_TOKEN)
                        .claim(AppConstant.USERNAME, authentication.getName())
                        .claim(AppConstant.ID, userVO.getUser().getUserDetail().getId())
                        .claim(AppConstant.AUTHORITIES, populateAuthorities(authentication.getAuthorities()))
                        .setIssuedAt(new Date()).setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 300000000))
                        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, AppConstant.JWT_KEY).compact();
                log.info("Auth token {} generated for {}", jwt, authentication.getName());
                response.setHeader(AUTHORIZATION, jwt);
            }
        } else {
            request.setAttribute("errorKey", errorMessageKey);
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String populateAuthorities(Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> collection) {
        Set<String> authoritiesSet = new HashSet<>();
        for (GrantedAuthority authority : collection) {
            authoritiesSet.add(authority.getAuthority());
        }
        return String.join(AppConstant.COMMA, authoritiesSet);
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of test is it? Unit test or spring integration test (sth like `@WebMvcTest`, `@SpringBootTest` etc)

Comment: Write down your whole test please

Comment: I've added my full code in the original question. I want to cover this `populateAuthorities` in code coverage. How to mock this? The rest I've done already.

Comment: where is the code of the test?

Comment: What is the value of `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` in your test? Is it a mock? How to you set up the mock?